# How to set ranges on data from SQL Server in ASP.NET with c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a page on which there is a map of India. I have inserted data into the SQL Server database about economic indicators. I have also placed a map of India on the webpage.

I want to be able to retrieve the data from the database and then get the greatest value from the data and set it as 100%. Then based on that if a value falls between 0 to 20% a that part of the map should be a certain color. If it falls between 20 to 40% it will be a different color and so on.

I am new to ASP.NET and SQL Server and not sure how to do this. I really need help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT states, 
                value, 
                ( value / NULLIF(Max(value) 
                                   OVER(), 0) ) * 100 AS [Percent] 
         FROM   yourtable) 
SELECT states, 
       value, 
       color = CASE 
                 WHEN [percent] BETWEEN 0 AND 20 THEN 'X color' 
                 WHEN [percent] BETWEEN 21 AND 40 THEN 'Y color' 
                 WHEN [percent] BETWEEN 41 AND 60 THEN 'X color' 
                 .....
               END 
FROM   cte
```

**Notes :**

- Formula used to calculate percentage `(Value/max_value) * 100`. Please correct if it is wrong.
- Considering `value` as the column for which you need to find percentage
- `NULLIF` is used to avoid *divide by zero* error
- `Max() Over()` is to find the largest value in your table